# Why do Jews have more commandments than Noahides?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, noachide-laws, negative-commandments

Out of curiosity. Why are there 613 laws for Jews and only 7 laws for Gentiles, and both Jews and Gentiles will get the same reward for obeying those laws?

Comment: Nice question, Orly - welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Welcome Orly. What makes you believe that "both Jews and Gentiles will get the same reward for obeying those laws"?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like two separate questions.

One, why the differing amounts; two, why same reward for Jews and Noahides.

Latter question is making an assumption that the sum total of reward is equal.

I would say that all are equal insofar as all are rewarded similarly for what they are commanded to observe. Jews being obligated in more will necessarily get more reward overall. However all are rewarded for what they are commanded in and observe.

As for the former, I would say that history showed that a universal Noahide moral code wasn't enough to keep the world on track.

A core group of extraordinarily God aware people became necessary—in tandem with the general moral code—to keep God awareness front and center.

Enter the Jews.